# Commandline switch/macro for Powerpoint 2010

Tags: vba, command-line, powerpoint

Is there a switch or a general macro (that can be applied to any ppt file) to save a ppt file to png files?

Comment: does the below work for you? if so, you can select the hollow checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no commandline switch for this. There are two possible options with switches though, one is `/M` (macro), which means you can run a macro in your PPTX (and that macro could save to .PNG) or `/PT` (print to) and print to OneNote (if you have it) and those images will be PNG. See [Command-line switches for PowerPoint 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/command-line-switches-for-powerpoint-2007-and-the-powerpoint-viewer-2007-HA010153889.aspx) (which are the same as 2010) for more details.

A macro would look like this:

```
Sub PrintToPng()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    ap.SaveAs ap.Path & "\" & "new", ppSaveAsPNG
End Sub
```

This will save each slide as it's own PNG in a subfolder named "new" at the same folder where the presentation was saved.