# Powerpoint Process works in standalone console project, but not integrated project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, process

I'm trying to run a local process using C# to call Powerpoint and convert a .pdf to a .ppt.

I made a standalone console app, in hopes of reproducing and isolating the problem.
Unfortunately, it works for the standalone version, but not with the integrated version.

When it doesn't work, it throws no exceptions. It just silently fails to create the .pdf file.

### NEW:

I'm getting an error on the event log:

```
Microsoft PowerPoint
PowerPoint can't do this because a dialog box is open. Please close the dialog box to continue.
P1: 400205
P2: 15.0.4420.1017
```

I don't see any sort of dialog box when running the console commands, the standalone console application, or running the integrated web project on my local machine.

The /pt command is supposed to be silent, as per [the official documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/command-line-switches-for-powerpoint-2007-and-the-powerpoint-viewer-2007-HA010153889.aspx).

I can set the `Identity` of the `ApplicationPool` the project is running under to the user that I log in as, and I no longer get the above error in the event log. However, I get no other errors (that I can tell are related) from the event log.

It still doesn't work, however. Powerpoint or PDFCreator still crashes, and doesn't create the .pdf.

I also tried to run my working console app by calling it as a `Process` from my integrated issue, and that didn't work either.

### The working console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\POWERPNT.exe\"";
        psi.Arguments = "/pt \"PDFCreator\" \"\" \"\" dd0e03ff-f386-4e65-b89d-72c7f1ee502d.pptx";
        psi.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Temp";
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.ErrorDialog = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        try
        {
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                var outString = new StringBuilder(100);
                exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => outString.AppendLine(e.Data);
                exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                var errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("errors reported 1");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          ex.ToString();
          Console.WriteLine("Errors reported 2 ");
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(psi.FileName);
        Console.WriteLine(psi.Arguments);
        Console.WriteLine(psi.WorkingDirectory);
    }
}
}
```

It prints

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\POWERPNT.exe"
/pt "PDFCreator" "" "" dd0e03ff-f386-4e65-b89d-72c7f1ee502d.pptx
C:\Temp
```

### The not working integrated application:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

namespace CT.Services.Helper
{
    public static class ExecutableRunner
    {
        public static ExecutableResult RunExeNamed(string exeFilename, string commandLineArgs)
    {
        return RunExeNamed(exeFilename, commandLineArgs, null);
    }

    public static ExecutableResult RunExeNamed(string exeFilename, string commandLineArgs, string workingDirectory)
    {
        var result = new ExecutableResult { WasSuccessful = true };

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName =  "\""+exeFilename+"\"";
        psi.Arguments = commandLineArgs;
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workingDirectory))
        {
            psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        }
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
        psi.ErrorDialog = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
                var outString = new StringBuilder(100);
                // use ansynchronous reading for at least one of the streams
                // to avoid deadlock
                exeProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => outString.AppendLine(e.Data);
                exeProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
                // now read the StandardError stream to the end
                // this will cause our main thread to wait for the
                // stream to close (which is when ffmpeg quits)
                var errString = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errString))
                {
                    result.WasSuccessful = false;
                    result.ErrorMessage = errString;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.WasSuccessful = false;
            result.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        }
        Debug.WriteLine(psi.FileName);
        Debug.WriteLine(psi.Arguments);
        Debug.WriteLine(psi.WorkingDirectory);
        return result;
    }
}

public class ExecutableResult
{
    public bool WasSuccessful { get; set; }

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

}

it prints

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\POWERPNT.exe"
/pt "PDFCreator" "" "" dd0e03ff-f386-4e65-b89d-72c7f1ee502d.pptx
C:\Temp
```

I would think that one of the strings I'm using as the file path or console command would be wrong, so I had them printed to the console, but you can see that those aren't the issue.

Comment: Did you look at windows event log to see if any errors were logged?

Comment: Where do you specify the output file? I can't see it!

Comment: @ArashN The output file gets created from the .ppt automatically. It shares the same name and directory as the input file.

Comment: @Hogan I don't really know how to use the windows event log, but I think I took a peek and saw nothing.

Comment: Try looking at StandardOutput instead of StandardError in your integrated solution. It might give you a clue as to what is going on.

Comment: @Jason If `StandardOutput` is the output generated by the external process being run, then there isn't going to be any.

Comment: @Hogan, I actually do get errors in the event log, upon further inspection. See above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last try ;-)
You could use Interop, open the file and afterwards save it as pdf.

For this little example to work you need to reference the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint assembly and the Microsoft.Office.Core namespace (found in the "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" assembly which is located under the COM assemblies).

Little Example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the specified source file and saves it as pdf with the
/// specified destination filename.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sourceFilename">The filename of the file to be converted into a pdf.</param>
/// <param name="destinationFilename">The filename of the pdf.</param>
/// <exception cref="System.IO.FileNotFoundException">Is thrown if the specified source file does not exist.</exception>
/// <exception cref="System.Exception">Is thrown if something went wrong during the convertation process.</exception>
public static void SaveAsPDF(string sourceFilename, string destinationFilename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(sourceFilename))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(string.Format("The specified file {0} does not exist.", sourceFilename), sourceFilename);
    }

    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

        app.Presentations.Open(sourceFilename).SaveAs(destinationFilename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF);
        app.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to convert {0} to {1}", sourceFilename, destinationFilename), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you specify the 3 additional parameters in .Open with Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse it shouldn't event show a window.

Comment: Is this a .vb script or a .c# script or what?

Comment: This is C# code. You can just call it directly from whereever you want in your application ;-)

Comment: And how do I download/install/reference these Microsoft Office assemblies?

Comment: Usually you just add the references in Visual Studio directly by clicking with the right mouse button on the "References" folder in your project and afterwards select "Add Reference...". Now search for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint under "Assemblies" -> "Framework" and for "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" under "COM" -> "Type Libraries". If you do not have Office 2010 it could be "Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library" I guess...

Comment: They were actually under "Extensions", not "Framework". My Object Library was actually v15

Comment: Do you use Visual Studio 2012 or 2010?
I'm using 2012.

Comment: Hm... interessting. However - the important thing is that you have found them ;-)

Comment: I'm getting an error "HRESULT E_FAIL" from the "Open" command

Comment: Which Office Version do you use and can you print the exact error message of the exception including inner exceptions (if available).
And: How did you execute it? From the web application with the different user context you mentioned somewhere above?
And: Could you also paste the specified arguments please?

Comment: 2013. I launched it from the command line. I can't paste the errors right now because I can't copy from the command line for some reason. The Params are `ppt.pptx. pdf.pdf`

Comment: And what did you specify as the command line arguments? As far as I know something like "HRESULT E_FAIL" can occur if you specify a wrong path or doulbe \\ or things like that.
In order to copy from the command line you have to mark the text and copy it afterwards ;-)

Comment: I would suggest specifying the complete path including the filename e.g. C:\TEMP\a.pptx C:\TEMP\a.pdf
I could imagine that PowerPoint want's to write somewhere where the context your app is running under has no permission to do so.

Comment: Hey, it works! Sadly, a small progress bar pops up and says "Publishing", but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work unless you open a powerpoint first, for some sort of cache reasons. If you run the commands from a cold boot, you get the error. If you open powerpoint itself to a blank presentation, you get the error. If you open one of the powerpoints you want to convert, a REAL powerpoint, then it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be a problem with the permissions of the application pool? Maybe it does not have permissions to perform all the actions you want to - you could check that by executing your console application under the same context as the application pool is running.

Comment: How would I change the application pool?

Comment: If there was a permission error it would show up in the event log.

Comment: I just know that you can try to run your application with the user specified in the application pool by using e.g. the runas command but I guess Hogan is right, there should be some entries in the event log if it were the permission issue.

Comment: @Hogan Actually, I do get an error in the event log. I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea (not sure if it is a stupid one or not). As far as I remember powerpoint (at least since 2010) is able to save directly to pdf. For 2007 you can use a microsoft plugin called "Save as PDF" which can be found here [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=7&mstLocPickShow=True).

Using the provided [Solution from Todd Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216050/commandline-switch-macro-for-powerpoint-2010) you could (theoretically) execute a macro at startup which could store the file directly as PDF (without printing and hopefully without dialog box).

**Update:**

I've tried it right now - problem is you have to store the macro in the presentation, therfore you have to use the pptm file format. Next you have to open the file once and activate the macro execution (is shown on the top of the editing screen). After that you can simply execute it from the command line like

```
POWERPNT.EXE /M Filename.pptm SaveAsPDF
```

The macro looks like this:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim ap As Presentation: Set ap = ActivePresentation
    ap.SaveAs ap.Path & "\" & ap.Name, ppSaveAsPDF
    PowerPoint.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried using a script before, but it opens the powerpoint window briefly. Not technically a dialog box, though. This might be different, since I've never used /M before

Comment: Because of the window that opens?

Comment: Because of storing the macro in the presentation and forcing users to use the .pptm file format, then opening the file once and activating the macro execution. I can't ask my users to do all that before uploading a  file

Answer (score 0):

> The integrated version of the code is part of a web application

1. Provide access to the current working directory where this file is being created for the app pool user and verify it has Read/Write.
2. Check the Temp directory on the server for the app-pool process user and verify that the process has read/write access to the temp directory.

---

Edit Upon seeing the event log.

Asp.net should not be using any application which is a user interactive process. You need to find a different application to create these powerpoint slides that is asp.net friendly or determine what Powerpoint is trying to do when it opens a dialog.

Comment: How do I do #1? Right now the "Identity" of the default app pool is "LocalSystem".

Comment: @Curtis you are dealing with a user interactive process. Asp.Net is not designed for that. See my edit. Sorry.

Comment: What is defined as a "user interactive process"? Powerpoint is supposed to be opening silently, running the process, and then closing. It's not supposed to ask the user for any interaction

Comment: @Curtis Microsoft Office apps are notorious for not behaving, do a search on Excel and Asp.net. That doesn't mean what you are doing is interactive, but Powerpoint is running into something (most likely it can't create the file and is opening a File Open Dialog box) and poping up a dialog; per *PowerPoint can't do this because a dialog box is open.*. Determine where the powerpoint is trying create the file and that may solve the issue.

Comment: I can run a console commands (or the standalone console program), and no dialog box ever opens, it works, and I don't get the error. I can run the integrated version on my local machine and no dialog box ever opens, and it doesn't work

Comment: @Curtis sure because the console's CWD is the same as the application exe and there are no rights issues for the user kicking off the process. For whatever reason the LocalSystem user running in the CWD of the Asp.Net web site does not have authorization to do (save file in CWD?) whatever Powerpoint is trying to do at that moment. That is the rub....

Comment: How do I set the LocalSystem permissions?

Comment: @Curtis Right click properties on the target directory in the file explorer and provide permissions to that user as specified in the connection pool.

Comment: How can I check the "user as specified in the connection pool"? The identity of the `DefaultAppPool` is `LocalSystem`

Comment: @Curtis Which version of IIS are you using? That will determine how you set the app pool process user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40130/discussion-between-curtis-and-omegaman)

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you are seeing this problem because you've never actually opened up Powerpoint under the user that is running the application in the environment where it's failing.
This will be the user that the application pool is running under and, as I see you've mentioned to OmegaMan, that user is LocalSystem.

When LocalSystem tries to open Powerpoint, then Powerpoint will be doing that thing that all Office applications do where they complete their install the first time a new user runs them.
You are not seeing this installation box in your console app or on your local system because you're running those under your own account and you've previously opened PowerPoint.

As OmegaMan rightly says Powerpoint is meant to be an interactive process so it is probably going to cause trouble even if you're very very careful. You'll end up with instances of Powerpoint staying open after they're supposed to have closed and loads of instances building up in the

That said, if you really want to get this running then you either need to get the application pool running as a user that has opened Powerpoint interactively, or change your code to use impersonation at the point where you need to run Powerpoint and then impersonate a user that has used it interactively to do what you need.

Comment: I set the `Identity` of the application pool to the user that I normally log in as, and I no longer get that error in the event log. However, it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: And what's the manifestation now? What are you seeing in your own logging?